# How can a Spring app in docker access mysql in host or cloud mysql?

Tags: mysql, spring, docker

How can I get my Spring App host in docker to access the mysql host on my host mechine(mac) or access a cloud mysql service?

I know if the mysql is another docker container, I can use link in docker. But this situation is not.

version: '3'

I tried the host mode, seems still get the connection refused.

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ADD ./build/libs/app.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","-Dspring.profiles.active=dev","/app.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    network_mode: "host"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

PS: 'java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev app.jar' on my host machine works fine.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

For latest mac docker, I can use docker.for.mac.localhost as hostname

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://docker.for.mac.localhost:3306/a_shares...
```

And some dark magic has been discussed in here [Accessing host machine from within docker container](https://forums.docker.com/t/accessing-host-machine-from-within-docker-container/14248/11)